# Https web service in .NET problem

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

i'm new in .NET and in SSL and i'm facing the problem with establishing the secure communication between the SOAP service and the client.
It was working fine with HTTP but now we have to apply the SSL.
We get the certificate from a CA.
next steps weres done are following:

1) enabling port used by the service using the `httpcfg set ssl -i 0.0.0.0:777 -h <thumbprintkey>`

2) `httpcfg set urlacl -u https://<domanname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure -a D:(A;;GA;;;AN)`

3)`httpcfg set iplisten-i 0.0.0.0:777`

The WebService code is following:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DeviceObservationConsumer_hostPCDData), new Uri("https://<domainname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure"));
host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, (string)"bd 35 ec c0 e6 b3 9a ac 74 09 09 c5 84 b8 fd 58 51 44 87 7d");

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDeviceObservationConsumer_Binding_Soap12), binding, "");

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
// If not, add one
if (smb == null)
    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpsGetEnabled = true;

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

// Add MEX endpoint
host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(), "mex");

host.Open();
```

The client code is following:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress("https://<domainname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure");

ChannelFactory<DeviceObservationConsumer_PortType> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<DeviceObservationConsumer_PortType>(binding, addr);
//myChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, (string)"bd 35 ec c0 e6 b3 9a ac 74 09 09 c5 84 b8 fd 58 51 44 87 7d");

DeviceObservationConsumer_PortType client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

CommunicatePCDDataRequest req = new CommunicatePCDDataRequest("ciao mamma guarda come mi diverto!");
CommunicatePCDDataResponse resp = client.CommunicatePCDData(req);

myChannelFactory.Close();
```

Both service and client are on the same PC.

I can't access the `https://<domanname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure` via browser (get the page not found error) and for sure the client can't access it neither.
where could be the problem could someone help me!!!!??

Thanks in advance,

Liudmila

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that WSHttpBinding uses HTTP as the transport protocol. For using HTTPS, you must specify HTTPS Transport protocol.

I suggest you try using custom binding (instead of WSHttpBinding which is preconfigured), with HttpsTransportBindingElement.

Your configuration would be similar to,

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding">
        <reliabileSession />
        <security><!--Your security section falls in here -->
        </security>
        <httpsTransport/>
        <textMessageEncoding />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

You may refer to [customBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731377.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. We are not using configuration file.

Comment: We changed the binding but still the same error..."An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://<PCname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."

Comment: ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DeviceObservationConsumer_hostPCDData), new Uri("https://<PCname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure"));
CustomBinding tlsbinding = new CustomBinding();
tlsbinding.Name = "TlsBinding";

HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
tlsbinding.Elements.Add(httpsTransport);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code we were using this time:
service:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DeviceObservationConsumer_hostPCDData), new Uri("https://<PCname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure"));
CustomBinding tlsbinding = new CustomBinding();
tlsbinding.Name = "TlsBinding";

HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
tlsbinding.Elements.Add(httpsTransport);

ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
// If not, add one
if (sdb == null)
    sdb = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
// If not, add one
if (smb == null)
    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpsGetEnabled = true;

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(sdb);
// Add MEX endpoint
host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(), "mex");
// Add application endpoint
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDeviceObservationConsumer_Binding_Soap12), tlsbinding, "");

host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, (string)"bd 35 ec c0 e6 b3 9a ac 74 09 09 c5 84 b8 fd 58 51 44 87 7d");
// hosting the WS
host.Open();
```

Client:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
binding.Name = "TlsBinding";

HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
binding.Elements.Add(httpsTransport);

EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress("https://<PCname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure");

ChannelFactory<DeviceObservationConsumer_PortType> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<DeviceObservationConsumer_PortType>(binding, addr);

DeviceObservationConsumer_PortType client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

CommunicatePCDDataRequest req = new CommunicatePCDDataRequest("ciao mamma guarda come mi diverto!");
CommunicatePCDDataResponse resp = client.CommunicatePCDData(req);

myChannelFactory.Close();
```

The rest of the steps were done to enable the SSL looks good for u?

Thanks again for the response!

Liudmila

Comment: no, it's still not working: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://<PCname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

Comment: Hi Mila, at a highlevel, it appears like the client deoes not provid the certificate information to the server and it neither negotiates for certificate. Would you like to try creating a client proxy from the metadata being exposed? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx

Comment: Another thing I would like to know is if you have checked if the service exposes metadata in the way you want? Check if https://<PCname>:777/TlsService/ServiceSecure/mex provides you a valid WSDL. If it does, client proxy created from it may work for you.